# What does do me the honour mean?

Tags: idioms, formal-language

I just found a formal phrase **do sb the honour**. And one of the examples of how it's used is:

**would you do me the honour of dining with me?**.

is that sentence synonymous with **would you mind dining with me?**. If they're not, please afford me the closest sentence to it. Thank you.

Comment: Would you honour me by dining with me?

Answer (score 1):

It is highly formal.  Probably so formal that it is usually used ironically.

Literally, it means "Would you honour me by dining with me".  It is highly polite because it means that "You are so honourable, that if you interact with me by dining with me, that would make me slightly less humble"

Nowadays it is more likely to be ironic:  Meaning "We're close friends and don't have any honour/humble relationship, so I can make a joke about me being humble and you being honourable, and you will understand that I don't really mean it..."

(Not that "Please afford me..." is also a highly formal expression.  "Please give me" or "tell me" would be more natural to the context of an internet forum)

It is hard to imagine a natural context in which you would need to say this.

Comment: Possibly just coincidence, but OP says *please **afford me** [an alternative]*, which imho is also "highly formal", to say the least. That doesn't look at all "natural" to me in the actual question text.

Comment: Indeed, and it contrasts with their previous question (about the use of "Relax!" when being pulled through a car window.)

Comment: I found exactly ***one*** written instance of [*please **afford** me the honor...*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22please+afford+me+the+honor%22) in Google Books (none at all for UK spelling ***honour***), as opposed to half-a-dozen instances of [*please **accord** me the honor...*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22please+accord+me+the+honor%22) Both sound "unlikely, but credible" to me, but I can't help wondering if one might be an "eggcorn" of the other (but which way round, I really couldn't say! :)